# Unable to resolve module @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

Getting this error after adding aws-amplify to the project, Did complete setup for aws-amplify according to the docs, then pod install and react-native run-ios
I have also tried changing the import statement as mentioned in the suggestion below error, still doesn't work, Thanks in advance.

````
  node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/node_modules
  node_modules
  ../node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  11 |  * and limitations under the License.
  12 |  */
> 13 | import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
     |                           ^
  14 | var MEMORY_KEY_PREFIX = '@MemoryStorage:';
  15 | var dataMemory = {};
  16 | /** @class */
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:234:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42)
    at resolve (/Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:629:33)
    at /Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:645:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:644:33)
    at /Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:329:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/monk/Projects/Airbnb/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:24)```
````

Comment: Clear the cache and retry

Comment: I got that too after updating aws-amplify. Explicitly adding the dependency fixed the problem, although not 100% sure that's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install Amplify libraries: [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react-native#install-amplify-libraries),

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

After that Try cleaning the project if there is an issue,

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && yarn cache clean --force && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules/
```

```
yarn install
```

```
rm -rf pods && pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the app from the emulator and reinstalled it and it finally worked after a long time of research that led to no emends!

Answer (score 0):

delete your node_modules & reinstall your node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while I was working with AWS Amplify. I was able to resolve it by just installing the package by firing this command.

```
npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolve so - in package.json

```
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage",
```

Comment: I don't recommend this at all as every time you do "npm i", it will look for the latest version including those with breaking changes and apply that to your project. This can introduce breaking changes that you might not see immediately.