# Error: Unable to resolve module @react-native-community/async-storage IOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to run my react native project In my IOS device. I start my server with `npx react-native start` then I start my app with Xcode. And I get this error:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module @react-native-community/async-storage from /Users/nicolelopez/dev/LeksPlay/src/Core/onboarding/utils/AuthDeviceStorage.js: @react-native-community/async-storage could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
> 1 | import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
    |                           ^
  2 |
  3 | const SHOULD_SHOW_ONBOARDING_FLOW = 'SHOULD_SHOW_ONBOARDING_FLOW'
```

what I have tried:

1. I have followed the commands I get In the error message:

```
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

2. i have deleted node_modules and my package.lock.json and have re-installed yarn and done a pod install.
3. i have tried to restart the computer
4. i have tried to do a `yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage`
5. i am running on node 14 - because I have run in to similar issues with a higher version of node.
6. i am running Xcode in Rosetta mode - since I am on a Mac M1.
7. i have tried to change my AsyncStorage import to `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';`
8. I have also tried to add `pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'`

but they all result in the same issue - with is the error code I posted. It gets no different no matter what I try. I am really new to react native, this may be a common issue but I can't seem to find anything that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the proper package called [`@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage).

The one you are using is **deprecated**, check it out on : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage

[image: deprecated @react-native-community/async-storage]

Having the two will lead to issues.

If the issue still persist, try to clear all the cached, there is a good tool that will help you clean your react native project: https://github.com/taboulot/rn-game-over

```
npx rn-game-over --all
```

If you still have the issue afterward, please update your question with the new detail.

Answer (score 1):

From the [usage documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage), it looks like you're importing Async Storage incorrectly. You should be importing from `@react-native-async-storage` and not from `@react-native-community`. Further, you seem to be confusing the two packages. Ensure you've completed the relevant [installation steps](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install) as well.

To install the correct package:

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

And to import Async Storage:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Comment: I did as you recommended and now I get the following error in Xcode: ```'logger/react_native_log.h' file not found```

Comment: This thread seems to have some helpful responses: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23944#issue-421378714

Answer (score 1):

as written in the documentation, it's not using @react-native-comunity. It means you should install the react-native-async-storage with :

```
npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

or

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

and not

```
npm install @react-native-community/async-storage
```

and if you got an issue or error while using the package,
here's the code I tried on my project to solve the problem:

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && yarn cache clean --force && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules/
```

i got the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67865721/8367675